# How to remove duplicates from rows in txt file through HIVE

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am new to HQL. I am trying to remove duplicate elements from 2 rows in HIVE.

The text file contains these two rows:

```
1 2 3 4 4 5 5 7 1 8 2 4 6 2
8 2 3 7 5 2 3 4 1 2 6 8 7 2
```

I need to remove duplicates from these 2 rows. I have created a table

```
CREATE TABLE remove_dup
(
elements STRING
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '/n';
```

Then I am loading data into this table. Now I can't remove the duplicates from these two rows. 
Can we also remove duplicates when there is no space between numbers?

Comment: And what are the duplicates? These rows are different. Please provide desired output

Comment: How are you expecting `FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','` to work without any commas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you are trying to remove the duplicate numbers you will need to create a new table as follow

```
CREATE TABLE remove_duplicates
(
elements STRING
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '/n';
```

And insert the data from one table to another using a regular expression to remove duplicates. The following regular expression works if your numbers are separated by space and it keep the first occurrence (if you want keep the last remove `reverse` from the query)

```
insert overwrite table remove_duplicates
select
 regexp_replace
    (
        rever(elements)
       ,'(?<=^| )(?<word>.*?) (?=.*(?<= )\\k<word>(?= |$))'
       ,''
    );
from
remove_dup;
```

It will create a new file (or files depending on the size of your data and your hive configuration) removing duplicates. You can look for the file location running the command to check the table location

```
describe formatted remove_duplicates;
```